# Program continues through the loop after a break statement

Tags: python, dictionary, break

I'm new to python and I was going through a few problem to practice. The question is:

```
#Given an array, return the first recurring character
#Example1 : array = [2,1,4,2,6,5,1,4]
#It should return 2
#Example 2 : array = [2,6,4,6,1,3,8,1,2]
#It should return 6


lsts = [2,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,4]
    
def findDouble(arrs):
  repeats = dict()
  for arr in arrs:
    repeats[arr] = repeats.get(arr, 0) + 1
    if repeats[arr] == 2: break
    print(arr)
        
        
    
findDouble(lsts)
    
#0(n)
```

My understanding is that after the "break" it should end the loop, so I should just get 2. Instead it goes through the entire thing and I get 2, 5, and 1. What am I not getting?

Comment: The loop does break once it gets to the second `2`.  But before that it finds 2, 5, and 1, and so it prints them.  It seems like you're expecting the code to find _any duplicate in the entire list_, but it doesn't do that -- it only finds duplicates in the _portion of the list that it has seen_.  Once it gets to the duplicated `2` value, it stops.

Comment: Think about it logically: under what conditions is `print(arr)` reached? What happens the first time through the loop - will `print(arr)` be reached? Why or why not? How about the second time? The third? Do you in fact want this `print` statement to be inside the loop? Why or why not?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Your hint made me realize my error. Thank You

Comment: Move the print statement to be inside the `if`, before the `break`.  As it is now, it prints every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time through the loop, `arrs` is 2.  That key does not yet exist in the dictionary, so `repeats[2]` is created with a value of 1, and the program prints `2`.

The second time through the loop, `arrs` is 5.  That key does not yet exist in the dictionary, so `repeats[5]` is created with a value of 1, and the program prints `5`.

The third time through the loop, `arrs` is 1.  That key does not yet exist in the dictionary, so `repeats[1]` is created with a value of 1, and the program prints `1`.

The fourth time through the loop, `arrs` is 2.  That key already exists in the dictionary with a value of 1, so `repeats[2]` is assigned a new value of 2, and the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is easier to understand if you put a `print(repeats)` right after assigning `repeats[arr] = ...`

Iteration 1: arr == 2

```
{2: 1} # key `2` was created and assigned `0 + 1`
```

Iteration 2: arr == 5

```
{2: 1, 5: 1} # key `5` created and assigned  `0 + 1`
```

Iteration 3: arr == 1

```
{2: 1, 5: 1, 1: 1} # key `1` created and assigned `0 + 1`
```

Iteration 4: arr == 2

```
{2: 2, 5: 1, 1: 1} # key `2` was already present, assigned `1 + 1`
repeat[arr] == 2: # evaluates to True, so it breaks
```